# Percentile Rank in Excel for Data Set with duplicate values

Tags: microsoft-excel

Suppose I have a dataset of 100 values with many duplicate values. If i use the standard PERCENTRANK function in excel, it ranks the data according to the proportion of values strictly below the data point, often resulting in no point getting 100 percentile.

I wanted to know the approach I could use for ranking based on the criteria of the proportion of data either equal to or below the data point as I want to ensure the highest possible percentile(thus also ensuring 100 percentile.)

Thank you!

Comment: construct your own formula, then let us know if you are having problems getting it to work as you desire.

Comment: @gns100 i figure the formula to be =((COUNTIF(D$3:D$103,"<="&D4)-1)/COUNT(D$3:D$103))*100. {This is the percentile rank for D4}. Is it correct?

Comment: That looks good. Maybe the only concern is with the `-1` part in your formula that would not get it to 100% if the maximum value in your range was selected. In the end it is your formula and you are in the best position to decide if  `-1` should or should not be there.  Post if you have additional questions.

Comment: @gns100 I decided that 100 percentile exactly doesnt make sense because you cannot score more than yourself; Plus the lowest score(if unique) should get 0 percentile, so I added the -1. Does it seem justifiable?

Comment: Yes, I think your reasoning is justifiable. you might want to wrap your formula like this: `max(formula,0)` because if you put a number less than the minimum you would otherwise get a negative number...

Comment: Do you want to keep TOP value?